# Display "X days ago" on Joomla articles

Tags: php, date, joomla

I´m trying to change the default Joomla articles date format (**April 24, 2016**) to a different way displaying something like **Published 1 day ago**.

Joomla use that piece of code to include the date:

`<?php echo $this->item->created; ?>`

It results in something like "2016-04-24 11:31:26"

Is it possible to get the desired "X days ago" only with that information?

Comment: you need to show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. This code display something like **+3 days**

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create( $this->item->created );
$datetime2 = date_create( $currentTime );
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```